# How to find the big theta?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Here's some code segment I'm trying to find the big-theta for:

```
i = 1 
while i ≤ n do          #loops Θ(n) times   
   A[i] = i             
   i = i + 1 
for j ← 1 to n do       #loops Θ(n) times
   i = j 
   while i ≤ n do       #loops n times at worst when j = 1, 1 times at best given j = n.
     A[i] = i 
     i = i + j
```

So given the inner while loop will be a summation of 1 to n, the big theta is Θ(n<sup>2</sup>. So does that mean the big theta is Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) for the entire code?

The first while loop and the inner while loop should be equal to Θ(n) + Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) which should just equal Θ(n<sup>2</sup>).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
for j = 1 to n step 1
  for i = j to n step j
    # constant time op
```

The double loop is `O(n⋅log(n))` because the number of iterations in the inner loop falls inversely to `j`. Counting the total number of iterations gives:

```
floor(n/1) + floor(n/2) + ... + floor(n/n)  <=  n⋅(1/1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n)  ∼  n⋅log(n)
```

The partial sums of the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) have logarithmic behavior asymptotically, so the above shows that the double loop is `O(n⋅log(n))`. That can be strengthened to `Θ(n⋅log(n))` with a [math argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/486521) involving the [Dirichlet Divisor Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function#Dirichlet%27s_divisor_problem).

---

[ *EDIT* ] For an alternative derivation of the lower bound that establishes the `Θ(n⋅log(n))` asymptote, it is enough to use the `<` part of the `x - 1 < floor(x) <= x` inequality, avoiding the more elaborate math (linked above) that gives the exact expression.

```
floor(n/1) + floor(n/2) + ... + floor(n/n)  >  (n/1 - 1) + (n/2 - 1) + ... + (n/n - 1)
                                            =  n⋅(1/1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n) - n
                                            ∼  n⋅log(n) - n
                                            ∼  n⋅log(n)
```

Comment: Ahh! I didn't notice at all the i = i + j that was involved in the inner while loop. Thanks. So given that nlog(n) grows faster with n than just n, the theta for the entire code should be Θ(n⋅log(n)) given Θ(n⋅log(n)) + Θ(n) = Θ(n⋅log(n))?

Comment: @CD'A Right, the first Θ(n) loop doesn't change the Θ(n⋅log(n)) total.